# Reading and storing every second line

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I am creating a small search engine to find values in files and store them. I have a txt file with the data:

```
link1
cat, dog, bird
link2
car, wheel, chair
```

There is a code to read and store, but the index map is empty.

```
int function(string filename, map<string, set<string>>& index) {

    int counter = 0;
    set <string> tokens;
    
    ifstream inStream;
    inStream.open(filename);
    if (inStream.fail()){
        counter = 0;
    }
    string http, definition;

    while (getline(inStream, http) && getline(inStream, definition)){
        for (auto v : tokens){
            index[v].insert(http);
            counter++
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: This cannot be real code that compiles, due to obvious typos and syntax errors. Although the logical bug appears to be obvious, it cannot be authoritatively stated due to the fact that the shown code is not real. Can you show actual code that meets all of Stackoverflow's requirements for a [mre]?

Comment: What is ```index```?

Comment: `tokens` is empty, so `for (auto v : tokens)` loop never runs and `index` is never updated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to split the items in each second line.

This is basically very simple.

You can use the well known `std::getline` with [delimiter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) concept.

The corrected version of your code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

std::istringstream fileSimulationStream{R"(link1
cat, dog, bird
link2
car, wheel, chair)"};

int main() {
    
    // Resulting data
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> data;
    
    // Read all lines from file. always 2 lines in one shot
    for (std::string link{}, item{}; std::getline(fileSimulationStream, link) and std::getline(fileSimulationStream, item); ) {
        
        // Put line in an istringstream for further extraction
        std::istringstream iss{item};
        
        // Read the items
        std::set<std::string> tempSet{}; std::string tempString{};
        while (std::getline(iss, tempString, ',')) tempSet.insert(tempString);
        
        // Now add everything to the map
        data[link] = std::move(tempSet);
    }
    // Create some debug output
    for (const auto&[key, set] : data) {
        std::cout << key << "\t--> ";
        for (const std::string s : set) std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```